# Is there any shortcut for parent folder in console?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I would like to know if there is any plugins and/or utilities that could make my life MUCH MORE easier.

When moving from folder to folder through console, I can use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key on my keyboard to autocomplete a folder, look for a folder (double tap) or simply to express that I want to go "forward" with my searches.

When coding, the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is used to "push" the code "forward" or to the right. To "pull" the code "backward", you can use the combination of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keys.

Is there an equivalent for, as an example, pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keys to write `../` in the console for me? Or to let me know I'm at the root level and that I can't go "backward" anymore?

**Examples of usage:**

Case 1:

`user@server:/$ cd ~/Desktop/folder1/`

after <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

`user@server:/$ cd ~/Desktop/`(Remove the last written folder. No more backspace spam!! :D )

Case 2:

`user@server:/$ cd`

after <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

`user@server:/$ cd` (Because I'm at root and can't go back)

Case 3:

`user@server:/home/Desktop/folder1$ cd`

after <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

`user@server:/home/Desktop/folder1$ cd ../` (Because I can go back to `Desktop`)

I know that sounds lazy. I know I'm lazy.

Anyways, thanks for the suggestions! (:

**Edit:**
Just to be clear. I gave as an example the `cd` command, but what I want could be applied to any command/executable. It would be considered a basic use just like <kbd>Tab</kbd> is used to autocomplete.

Comment: If you want to be lazier, use `cd ..` instead of `cd ../` and save one keystroke :)

Comment: What I'm saying is that with an additionnal feature such as this one, you could almost only use <kbd>Tab</kbd> and/or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go through directories :P But hey, I understand that some folks don't care about that possible upgrade.

Comment: Luckily I learned how to do it a week ago and just needed to fine-tune a solution for this question.

Comment: [crosspost](https://superuser.com/q/1433763/172747)

Comment: @bummi I've posted this on AskUbuntu, SuperUser and Unix&Linux! (: I hope to get more points of view from yall :P

Answer (score 2):

Create this file `/home/$USER/.inputrc` with the following:

```
# ~/.inputrc - complements /etc/inputrc - global inputrc for libreadline
# April 15, 2019
# See readline(3readline) and `info rluserman' for more information.

$include /etc/inputrc

# Insert key to togged overwrite-mode
"\e[2~": overwrite-mode

# April 22, 2019 AU Q&A: https://askubuntu.com/q/1135306/307523
# Make Shift-tab act like "cd ../" (move to parent directory)
"\e[Z": "cd ../"
```

Save the file and open a new terminal.

Now you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to send `cd ../` to the terminal.

Also included in the settings you can press <kbd>Insert</kbd> key to toggle between character overwrite (replace) mode and insert mode.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to make this into a switch case taking what's already writen in console, ex: `myExe.exe folder0/folder1/file0`, and determine what case to use? Shift+Tab combinaison on this line of command would change to `myExe.exe folder0/folder1/`? (: There has to be a way right? Since the Tab key, when hit twice in a folder containing multiple subdolders, is kinda like the `ls` command, but when there's already letters to specify the wanted folder, it autocompletes the said folder name (kinda like a switch case)

Comment: When you look at `/etc/inputrc` you will see there are `$if` statements to determine a given state and react in two different methods. Such programming skills are above my AU paygrade though :( Hopefully someone else can take what I've posted and run with it :)

Comment: Thanks allot for the info! (: I'll certainly use the code you wrote as a base to what I want to accomplish!

Comment: If you improve the code remember to post your own answer and click the grey check mark to it so others know your solution works. I wish you good luck and good programming!

Comment: The answer you wrote gave me knowledge on how to code a shortcut. (`Shift` + `Tab` writes `cd ..` in the console) Which is answering part of my question but not everything. It does not tell me how to change `myExe myFolder/myChildFolder/` to `myExe myFolder/` and many more use case and/or how to read and change the `myFolder/` section directly from/to the console. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I may have used the word "console" when I meant "Terminal" and/or "Bash"... Sorry if it caused confusion (: