# In gnome-terminal only 2 out of 3 zoom keys work

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

In `gnome-terminal` Ubuntu Unity 16.04 LTS the menu works for all three zoom features within the **View** menu:

- Zoom In
- Zoom Out
- Normal Size

Only two shortcut keys work:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> works to **Zoom In**
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> works to **Zoom Out**.

Attempting to restore **Normal Size** I found <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> do not work. These key combinations perform as if the <kbd>Enter</kbd> was used.

### My modified setup

```
$ cat .inputrc

# ~/.inputrc - complements /etc/inputrc - global inputrc for libreadline
# April 15, 2019
# See readline(3readline) and `info rluserman' for more information.

$include /etc/inputrc

# Insert key to togged overwrite-mode
"\e[2~": overwrite-mode

# April 22, 2019 AU Q&A: https://askubuntu.com/q/1135306/307523
# Make Shift-tab act like "cd ../" (move to parent directory)
"\e[Z": "cd ../"
```

### Custom keyboard shortcuts

[image: keyboard shortcuts.png]

- I believe these are standard. At least I don't remember changing them.
- I reviewed all the other shortcuts and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> doesn't appear.

### Ubuntu skeleton setup

```
$ cat /etc/inputrc

# /etc/inputrc - global inputrc for libreadline
# See readline(3readline) and `info rluserman' for more information.

# Be 8 bit clean.
set input-meta on
set output-meta on

# To allow the use of 8bit-characters like the german umlauts, uncomment
# the line below. However this makes the meta key not work as a meta key,
# which is annoying to those which don't need to type in 8-bit characters.

# set convert-meta off

# try to enable the application keypad when it is called.  Some systems
# need this to enable the arrow keys.
# set enable-keypad on

# see /usr/share/doc/bash/inputrc.arrows for other codes of arrow keys

# do not bell on tab-completion
# set bell-style none
# set bell-style visible

# some defaults / modifications for the emacs mode
$if mode=emacs

# allow the use of the Home/End keys
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line

# allow the use of the Delete/Insert keys
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert

# mappings for "page up" and "page down" to step to the beginning/end
# of the history
# "\e[5~": beginning-of-history
# "\e[6~": end-of-history

# alternate mappings for "page up" and "page down" to search the history
# "\e[5~": history-search-backward
# "\e[6~": history-search-forward

# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word

$if term=rxvt
"\e[7~": beginning-of-line
"\e[8~": end-of-line
"\eOc": forward-word
"\eOd": backward-word
$endif

# for non RH/Debian xterm, can't hurt for RH/Debian xterm
# "\eOH": beginning-of-line
# "\eOF": end-of-line

# for freebsd console
# "\e[H": beginning-of-line
# "\e[F": end-of-line

$endif
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default shortcut for restoring the zoom in gnome-terminal, as in many other apps, is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> (*zero*)

You can alter it in *gnome-terminal's* preferences, that is, neither in inputrc nor among the global desktop-wide shortcuts.

Comment: Ohhhh I feel like such a zero :P Thanks for the answer!